# On the share vs on shares

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context

> "Well, after the Civil War they died off pretty fast, livin' in poverty on the plantation, which was allowed to go to ruin. Finally only four girls were left, sisters, livin' in the old house and ekin' out a bare livin', with a few blacks livin' in the old slave huts and workin' the fields **on the share**. They kept to themselves, bein' proud, and ashamed of their poverty. Folks wouldn't see them for months at a time. When they needed supplies they sent a Negro to town after them.

(from "Pigeons from Hell" by Robert E. Howard, 1938)

The above "on the share" seems not be a correct form; a phrase found in the dictionary, "on shares," is seemingly more proper for the above sentence.

Can "on the share" also be used?

Comment: It's referring to "sharecropping", where the person actually tilling the soil effectively rented the land, and paid the rent with a "share" of the "crop".  There are no doubt many different idioms that have been used to describe this setup.

Comment: To my knowledge this setup still exists today, in some parts of the US.  And, while white owner/black sharecropper was the norm (and may still be), it was/is not a given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working a farm or field "on the share" means working as a *sharecropper*: that is, the blacks were allowed to farm the sisters' land in return for giving a share of the harvest to the sisters.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it clear, there are probably several different idioms for the sharecropper's position (including ["sharecropper"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sharecropper)).  There is no "preferred" term ("sharecropper" is somewhat derogatory), and "on the share" was almost certainly an accepted (and likely "sanitized") idiom in 1938 when the above was written.